# Express the area of a circle as a function of $x$

Tags: geometry

I am having problems understanding how to extract this information into a formula.

> A wire of length $x$ is bent into the shape of a circle. Express the area of the circle as a function of $x$

(Note: i do have have the answer to the question, my question is on how to extract the information)

Any help would be much appreciated, Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wire of length $x$ is bent into the circumference of the circle. Therefore $x = 2πr$.
Therefore, we deduce $r = x/2π$.
Therefore area of the circle($A$) = $πr^2$ =$π(x/2π)^2$ [putting value of $r$]

Thus area in function of $x$ is $x^2$$/$$4π$.

Comment: Thank You! This finally makes sense!, Cheers

Comment: Keep following! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

The perimeter  $\displaystyle 2\pi r=x$ where $r$ is the radius

Now, what is the formula of area in terms of radius?

Comment: the formula for area is $A=πr^2$ , i do not know how to get the area in terms of the radius

Comment: @foo, What are $P,R$ ?

Comment: (i do not know all of the formatting yet for this site, had to copy and paste)

Comment: @foo, Can you express $A$ in terms of $x$ eliminating $r$

Comment: Sorry, i really do not understand how to do that step..

Comment: @foo, $$x^2=(2\pir)^2, A=\pi\cdot r^2$$ divide the first relation by the second